# how can I extract a position of values that match a logical selection in a matrix in r?

Tags: r, matrix, sapply

How can I extract the position of every 0 per column in a following matrix:

```
bm <- matrix(c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),5,3)
```

that gives a matrix like:

```
+---+---+---+
| x | y | z |
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
```

So I want to have a data frame or matrix in whichever form it's easier with the positions of each 0 according to the rows or column position. Something like:

```
+---+---+---+
| x | y | z |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 |   | 3 |
+---+---+---+
|   |   | 4 |
+---+---+---+
|   |   | 5 |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

It's a very basic question that I did not find an answer right away yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we don't want to reorder the index by column

```
row(bm) * !bm
```

If we want to reorder, an option is `row` multiplied with the logical matrix and then reorder the positions

```
apply(row(bm)* !bm, 2, function(x) c(x[x!=0], x[x==0]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    2
#[2,]    3    0    3
#[3,]    0    0    4
#[4,]    0    0    5
#[5,]    0    0    0
```

---

Or using `order`

```
apply(row(bm) * !bm, 2, function(x) x[order(!x)])
```

---

Or another option

```
sapply(asplit(replace(row(bm), !!bm, NA), 2),
       function(x)  x[order(is.na(x))])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find row/column index of each position where `bm = 0`

```
mat <- which(bm == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)

#     row col
#[1,]   1   1
#[2,]   3   1
#[3,]   2   2
#[4,]   2   3
#[5,]   3   3
#[6,]   4   3
#[7,]   5   3
```

Matrices/Dataframes cannot have unequal length, so we can `split` row index by column index to get a named list.

```
split(mat[, 1], mat[, 2])

#$`1`
#[1] 1 3

#$`2`
#[1] 2

#$`3`
#[1] 2 3 4 5
```